# System for mining Ethereum

Tags: mining

What do you think about this system. I want to mine Ethereum.

CPU : AMD Fx-4300
GPU : 3x AMD R9 280X
Power Supply :  FSP 1000W 80+ Gold
Motherboard : MSI 990FXA-GD65
500GB HDD
4GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

Awesome!

You should get about 75 Mhash/s which gives you about $30 of Ether per day.

Download geth and ethminer (inside Ethereum 0.9.41)

Those are the commands I use on my R9 Fury...

---

First BAT

> geth --rpc --etherbase "0xe690A9bD2653007138808338532c493E82828bBF"

---

Second BAT

> ethminer -G -F http://127.0.0.1:8545
>
> tail -f geth.log